# wp7 multiple tiles from single app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was wondering how I can have multiple tiles from 1 app.

What I'm thinking is having a master tile that is your admin tile.  Then the user can setup children tiles where they would be pinned to the main screen.  These children tiles would have children only functionality.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple secondary tiles:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltile.create(v=VS.92).aspx